# How to disable entire column in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I want to disable entire column based on specific condition that column contains onCellClicked  event but i don't want it to fire

Comment: For future reference, here is complete info on [disabling checkbox in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012540/7977581).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define [`editable`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/) property in `colDef`

```
editable: false <-- edit would be disabled for needed column
```

> Updated

Header checkbox can be used for row-selection, for other things, you should create custom handlers by yourself.

For display handling, you need to create [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/)

For edit handling, you need to create own [`cellEditor`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/)

Based on the [official demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/):

> Here is worked sample for your case <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/O2l9KN7iTJxBwyYEQLJJ?p=preview)</kbd>

`cellRenderer` - checkbox would be displayed as an icon

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ICellRendererAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
    selector: '',
    template: `
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <span *ngIf="params.value == true" title='true' class='ag-icon ag-icon-tick content-icon'></span>
        <span *ngIf="params.value == false" title='false' class='ag-icon ag-icon-cross content-icon'></span>
        <span *ngIf="!params.value"></span>
    </div>
    `
})
export class CheckboxRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    private params: any;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    refresh(params):boolean{
      return true;
    }
}
```

`cellEditor` - double click on the cell will provide edit mode (if its possible, based on `colDef`- `editable` property)

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ICellEditorAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
    selector: '',
    template: `<input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue">`,
})

export class ChekboxEditorComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp {

    private params: any;
    private checkboxValue:boolean;


    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.checkboxValue = this.params.value;
    }

    refresh(params):boolean{
      return true;
    }

    getValue(){
      return this.checkboxValue;
    }
}
```

And the last thing:
`editable: (params)=>{return params.node.data.checkbox != true}`

here there is a logic which will disable edit mode for `true` values in `column`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i used rowSelection: 'multiple' in column & want that entire column disable.

Comment: here is the plunker [https://plnkr.co/edit/FKzYGZd5rbUVKv1j5yQK?p=preview] i want that when grid loaded & checkboxes are checked (based on some condition) i want that first column Disable so checkboxes are not checked or unchecked.

Comment: I want to achieve following 1.load grid with checkboxes(some checkboxes are pre selected based on some condition) 2. user not able to select / deselect that checkboxes like they have only view rights not edit rights

Answer (score 0):

Using `gridOptions.isRowSelectable` we can set a particular row to be selectable or not selectable. Below is an example from the ag-grid documentation itself.
`gridOptions.isRowSelectable: function(rowNode) {
    return rowNode.data ? rowNode.data.year < 2007 : false;
}`

Comment: he said `column`, not `row`.

Comment: He commented that he used rowSelection multiple so I thought it was row selection. Thanks for mentioning it @un.spike